# Catching auth error on redis / heroko / node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

I'm running a redis / node.js server and had a

```
[Error: Auth error: Error: ERR max number of clients reached]
```

My current setup is, that I have a connection manager, that adds connections until the maximum number of concurrent connections for my heroku app (256, or 128 per dyno) is reached. If so, it just delivers an already existing connection. It's ultra fast and it's working.

However, yesterday night I got this error and I'm not able to reproduce it. It may be a rare error and I'm not sleeping well, knowing it's out there. Because: Once the error is thrown, my app is no longer reachable.

So my questions would be:

- is that kind of a connection manager a good idea?
- would it be a better idea to use that manager to wait for 'idle' to be called and the close the connection, meaning that I had to reestablish a connection everytime a requests kicks in (this is what I wanted to avoid)
- how can I stop my app from going down? Should i just flush the connection pool whenever an error occurs?

What are your general strategies for handling multiple concurrent connections with a given maximum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody is reading along:

The error was caused by a messed up redis 0.8.x that I deployed to live:

https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/issues/251

I was smart enough to remove the failed connections from the connection pool but forgot to call '.quit()' on it, hence the connection was out there in the wild but still a connection.